# gallery thumb slider jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, gallery

I have made something like gallery with thumbs and big image. Very basic. I would like to create sliding thumb div. I got div with 13 images, next and prev button. But i want to make only 4 images visible. Clicking on next button it shows next img ( i have created that ),what i need is, when it goes past 4th img, thumbs slide to next 4 images and so on. Also it would be nice to add infinite scrolling, so all thing goes around. I know about jquery's scrollable(), but that's not quite what i'm looking for. Would appreciate some materials, main concepts or simple examples....

```
<div id="thumbs">
    <ul>
    <li><img src="assets/img/prev.png" class="prev"></li>
    <li>
      <a href="assets/img/img1_large.jpg" onclick="return false">
      <img style="margin-left: 33px;" src="assets/img/thumbs/img1_thumb.jpg"/></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="assets/img/img2_large.jpg" onclick="return false">
      <img src="assets/img/thumbs/img2_thumb.jpg" /></a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="assets/img/img3_large.jpg" onclick="return false">
      <img src="assets/img/thumbs/img3_thumb.jpg" /></a>
        </li>

    <li>
      <a href="assets/img/img4_large.jpg" onclick="return false">
      <img src="assets/img/thumbs/img4_thumb.jpg" /></a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="assets/img/img5_large.jpg" onclick="return false">
      <img src="assets/img/thumbs/img5_thumb.jpg" /></a>
    </li>

    <li><img src="assets/img/next.png" class="next"></li>
</div>
```

Comment: check this link its a good video for building slider: http://freecourses.tutsplus.com/30-days-to-learn-jquery/the-obligatory-slider.html, i hope it helps

Comment: thanks, will keep that link in mind, but that's not my problem. To illustrate better, http://www.tn3gallery.com/?refCode=fe8775 . I want to creat thumbnail slider like that, except without mouseslide function.

What i got: Slider,thumbs, working next prev buttons, which select images and display them.
What i need: 4img div, which slides to next 4 img section, when previous section is ended +infinite scrolling, so when last img is selected, and next button is pressed, it comes back to first 4 images